# OpenMP on Kirin 650

Tags: arm, openmp

Basically, the Kirin 650 ARM core is the one in the Honor 5c phone from Huawei. I am trying to bench C++ code directly on the rooted phone I have. This code is executing Neon instructions and have OpenMP parallelization. When I execute OpenMP functions on the phone it returns:

```
Num Procs = 8
Num Threads = 1
Max Threads = 8
Num Devices = 0
Default Device = 0
Is Initial Device = 1
```

These infos seems coherent since the Kirin 650 has 8 cores. However it is also specified in the phone technical details that the Kirin can have 4 cores up to 1.7GHz (power saving cores) and 4 cores up to 2GHz (performance cores).

How does OpenMP handle these as they are asynchronous as I understand it ? With my benchmarks I see speedups when I test `No OpenMP` against `OpenMP - 2 threads` and `OpenMP - 4 threads` but my `OpenMP - 8 threads` results are disaster.

Does these cores share the same clock (I'm using the `clock_gettime` instruction from the Hayai library to bench everything) ? Do you have any advice when executing stuff with OpenMP on these kinds of platforms ?

Comment: Threads that run on faster cores finish first and then wait for the slower threads to complete, wasting resources. It is not impossible to program such a system using OpenMP, but only certain algorithms, specifically those from the "controller-worker" or "bag-of-tasks" kinds, will benefit. Also, forget about `schedule(static)` and use the _places_ model of OpenMP 4 to properly pin the threads.

Comment: by _places_ do you mean I should set the **OMP_PLACES** environment variable ? I've never used that and reading what it stands for confuses me a bit. If I understand it well, each core have its own thread set and they cannot be moved from a core to another, am I right ? So should I just _export OMP_PLACES=core_ ?

Comment: With places one can the OpenMP runtime in a quite generic way where to pin specific threads. By default the threads are allowed to migrate from one core to another. But thread pinning is only useful if the algorithm is able to distribute the workload to processing elements of different speed.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Perhaps you could post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @baptiste: Did Hristo's comment solve your problem?

Comment: Not really. We still haven't found a way to access all those cores. I don't know if there is a solution actually. We tried to launch scripts from a terminal instead using `adb` and it never goes past 4 cores used at a time so we think the kernel blocks the core usage. We also try to change the governor but we only manage to target the most powerful cores. We tried with a Honor 8 and we have the same issue...

Comment: For those who might be interested I also posted a related question on the OpenMP forum: http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1991&p=7802#p7802